unable to implement streaming while generating response of ollama
I am using langchain4j, PGVector and Ollama (llama3) for my RAG application
there is an API endpoint "/generate"  where the user gives a string and it returns the response generated by the Ollama model
but the response is sent directly
I want the response to come like ChatGPT i.e. streaming response.
Please help me
I am providing my sample controller

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


import dev.langchain4j.model.ollama.OllamaStreamingChatModel;
import dev.langchain4j.model.StreamingResponseHandler;
import dev.langchain4j.model.chat.StreamingChatLanguageModel;
import dev.langchain4j.data.message.AiMessage;
import dev.langchain4j.model.output.Response;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class OllamaController {
    private final StreamingChatLanguageModel streamingChatModel;

    public OllamaController() {
        this.streamingChatModel = OllamaStreamingChatModel.builder()
                .baseUrl("url")
                .modelName("llama3")
                .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
                .temperature(0.6)
                .build();
    }
    @PostMapping("/generate")
    public String generateResponse(@RequestBody String userMessage) {
        StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        CompletableFuture<Response<AiMessage>> futureResponse = new CompletableFuture<>();
        
        streamingChatModel.generate(userMessage, new StreamingResponseHandler<AiMessage>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(String token) {
                responseBuilder.append(token);
                System.out.print(token);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Response<AiMessage> response) {
                futureResponse.complete(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                futureResponse.completeExceptionally(error);
            }
        });
        
        futureResponse.join();
        return responseBuilder.toString();
    }
}


From this source, you can stream response like this:
Webflux
@PostMapping("/generate")
public Flux<String> generateResponse(@RequestBody String userMessage) {
    return Flux.create(fluxSink -> {
        streamingChatModel.generate(userMessage, new  StreamingResponseHandler<AiMessage>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(String token) {
                fluxSink.next(jsonString.getBytes());
             }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Response<AiMessage> response) {
                fluxSink.complete();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                fluxSink.error(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

StreamingResponseBody
@PostMapping("/generate")
public Flux<String> generateResponse(@RequestBody String userMessage) {
        StreamingResponseBody responseBody = response -> {
            streamingChatModel.generate(userMessage, new  StreamingResponseHandler<AiMessage>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(String token) {
                    response.write(jsonString.getBytes());
                    response.flush();
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Response<AiMessage> response) {
                    System.out.print("Complete");
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        };
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
            .body(responseBody);
}


as of now i am using web-flux

i've updated my answer with webflux
